# JBOSS 6 deployment issues, JAX-RS with jersey

Tags: java, jboss, jersey, jax-rs

**My questions are:**

*Q 1. How to enable Package Scanning in JBOSS, so that it may know that where to look for implementation classes and the providers(the one annotated with @Provider) in a war file?*

*Q 2. Why my filter was not registered by the application class, and I had to do it in web.xml?*

**Scenario**

I created a Jax-RS webservice using Jersey and deployed it in JBOSS-6, firstly I came across an error that depicts that JBOSS will not be able to Scan through the packages, that I have provided in the web.xml to find my Rest webservice implementations.
So the way around was to create an `Application` class,(I prevented myself from using the `ResourceConfig` provided by Jersey  itself for no specific reason) and registered my WebService implementation in the getClasses method like the following:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
         set.add(RESTWSImplementation.class);
         set.add(SomeFilter.class);
        return set;
    }   
}
```

it somewhat did the trick for me , but the filter was still not registered. i.e.

```
 set.add(SomeFilter.class);
```

seems like was not working, So I mentioned that filter in my web.xml like following,

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>test.SomeFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

then everything worked perfectly. However from below text, I was expecting it to get registered straight away.

[image]

***So again my questions are,***

1. How to enable Package Scanning in JBOSS, so that it may know that where to look for implementation classes and the providers(the one annotated with @Provider)?
2. Why my filter was not registered by the application class, and I had to do it in web.xml?

### Edit: pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>POCTEST</groupId>
  <artifactId>POCTEST</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Don't provide information as image which can be text.

Answer (score 2):

please show your pom.xml.

Probably your are using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${jaksonVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Try:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${restEasyVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${restEasyVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Edit:

Or you can try to add init param inside servlet tag(in web.xml):

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.your.package</param-value>
    </init-param>
```